# how to force model.matrix to use all levels of 2 categorical variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data

**Description**
I have 2 categorical variables and I want to turn them into columns - for each category exactly one column

**Progress**
Simple code to achive this:

```
d.data <- data.frame(a=as.factor(c("some1","some2","some3")), b = as.factor(c("other1","other3","other2")))
d.data.new <- data.frame(model.matrix(~a -1 + b -1, data=d.data))
names(d.data.new)
```

> [1] "asome1"  "asome2"  "asome3"  "bother2" "bother3"

"-1" works only for "a" variable which is represented by whole 3 levels, but "b" have only two - and I need whole 3.
Not really undarstand how "-1" works in this case for {formula} inside model.matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a model.matrix solution, but you can get the binary output using `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(d.data)))
```

---

Or another option would be to loop through the column names of 'd.data' and do the `model.matrix` separately on each column, `cbind` and change the column names (if required).

```
d1 <- do.call(cbind,lapply(names(d.data), function(i) 
                      model.matrix(~get(i)-1, d.data)))
colnames(d1) <- sub('.*\\)', '', colnames(d1))
```